# Passing multiple parameters to a modal jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

and I am trying to pass 2 parameters to the modal when it is called ... 1 is an object that contains several properties, and one is just a regular string.

Here is my showLocationModal call :

```
   var
    $ = window.jQuery,
     locationModalContainer = '#modal-location',
    locationModalOpts = {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: '520',
        height: '760',
        dialogClass: 'modal'
    }


    function showLocationModal()
    {

        $(locationModalContainer).dialog($.extend(locationModalOpts));
        $(locationModalContainer).dialog('open');
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".search button").click(function () {
            Regal.showLocationModal();
            $("span.icon-magnify-glass").trigger("click");
            return false;
        });
    });


    window.Regal = window.Regal || {};
    window.Regal.showLocationModal = showLocationModal;
```

This code works, but everytime I try to add the parms, it breaks. 
Also, how do I accept the parms in my Modal? 
I am new to jquery, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is working here http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/vTQmN/1/, what is the problem?

Comment: yes, this works ... this needs to be dual purpose, either they enter something in the main page header which the arguments get passed to an Ajax call which will populate the modal (this works), if they do not enter something or the modal is called from another process, we need to accept parameters in the modal to prepopulate the modal. I am just not certain how to code the second scenario, but thank you for your response

Comment: Careful with the way you are using $.extend(), passing a single object will extend the root jQuery object with your locationModalOpts. If you are trying to copy the object, pass in an empty object to extend first like this $.extend({}, locationModalOpts)